# Android RECORD_AUDIO permission in unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, audio-recording, android-permissions

android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO 
I'm not using this permission in my manifest file and I even searched in my whole project and didn't find it. But still when I try to install my app, it asks for this permission and if I click on it, it gives me msg

```
Microphone
provided by Android System
android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
```

I want it to be removed as I don't want to use it! Any idea how to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

One of library accessing microphone in script and I think unity adds permission based on that by it self.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont know who is adding it you can remove it in the final manifest by using xmlns tool like below

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:installLocation="auto">
...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" tools:node="remove" />
...
```

ofcourse just be careful and make sure no code really require it since you might crash if code or one of your plugins enters a point where it requires this permission to run